# CREATE PROCEDURE - how to check if successfully compiled?

Tags: oracle, client, oracle-call-interface

I'm using [OCILIB](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/).

Statements of the form `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AA1 AS BEGIN XXX; END;` are always successful (ie, no error or warning is reported). How can I check whether the statement was compiled correctly?

There should be a function to get that information (I hope).

Here is a quick & dirty example that shows the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ocilib.h>

void print_error() {
  printf("Error:");
  OCI_Error *err = OCI_GetLastError();
  if (err) printf(" %d: %s\n", OCI_ErrorGetOCICode(err), OCI_ErrorGetString(err));
  else printf(" no error.");
  printf("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  OCI_Connection *cn;
  OCI_Statement *st;

  OCI_EnableWarnings(TRUE);

  if (!OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT | OCI_ENV_CONTEXT)) {
    puts("Failed to initialize OCI");
    return 2;
  }

  cn = OCI_ConnectionCreate("XE", "<your user>", "<your pwd>", OCI_SESSION_DEFAULT);
  print_error();

  OCI_SetAutoCommit(cn, TRUE); print_error();
  st = OCI_StatementCreate(cn); print_error();

  OCI_ExecuteStmt(st, "create or replace procedure aaa as begin garbage end;");
  print_error();

  OCI_Cleanup();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./ocitest
Error: no error.
Error: no error.
Error: no error.
Error: no error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in OCILIB that was not reporting SQL Warnings properly. This is fixed and OCILIB repository is up to date with the fix :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status in the [`user_objects` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e24448/statviews_1158.htm):

```
select status
from user_objects
where object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
and object_name = 'AA1';
```

If that is not `VALID`, you can get the actual errors by querying the [`user_errors` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e24448/statviews_1086.htm):

```
select * -- or just line, position and text
from user_errors
where type = 'PROCEDURE'
and name = 'AA1'
order by sequence;
```

I'm surprised you don't get an exception, but this isn't a stack I use...

Comment: OK... but for this I must first extract the procedure name from the statement text. How do I do that (other than writing a parser myself)?

Comment: Um, not sure. You could look for any invalid object created in the last few seconds or minutes, but there might be more than one, and they might have been created by a different process; and if the procedure already existed then you'd have to look at `last_ddl_time` instead. Parsing might be safer. But now I'm thing you meant there should be an OCILIB function to get this info, not a SQL function as I first assumed. I don't know enough about OCILIB to comment on that, so maybe this is a fallback approach...